How to validate Post arguments in Django
I've seen plenty of solutions on how to validate Form field parameters, but I am not using Django templates or implementing the front-end in Django at all.  I'm looking purely for server-side backend validation.  Let's say I have
@api_view(['POST'])

def my_func(request):

And I want the data to be something like:
{
  "username" : <user>,
  "password" : <pw>,
  "age"      : <age>
}

I want to validate that username and password are strings, perhaps with a minimum length requirement.  And that age is a number, again, perhaps with other restrictions, such as min/max.
Is there a standard way to do this?

A universal standard is to use forms. You can still use them even though your views do not use django templates, you just instantiate the form instance manually instead. I'll show that below.
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator, MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class RequestBodyForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(20)])
    age      = forms.IntegerField(
                validators=[
                    MinValueValidator(18), 
                    MaxValueValidator(100)
                ])

# views.py
from .forms import RequestBodyForm

@api_view(['POST'])
def my_func(request):
    data = RequestBodyForm(request.POST)
    if data.is_valid():
        # Data was valid, proceed with whatever it is you need to do
    else:
        # Data was invalid, handle/return the failure

You are not limited to forms, however. DRF's serializers are up to the case, and I would advise to use this instead since you're using DRF anyway.
For your specific use-case, the serializer fields have built-in validation options:
# serializers.py
class RequestBodySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, min_length=10)
    age      = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=100, min_value=18)

Or you can add custom validation logic per field using the .validate_<field_name>() convention:
# serializers.py
class RequestBodySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    age      = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate_age(self):
        if age < 18 or age > 100:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Disallowed age")

